# Hadoop reducer ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when passing values from mapper

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to output two values from the mapper to the reducer by passing a string value but when I parse the string in the Mapper I get an out of bounds error. However, I made the string in the Mapper so I'm sure it has two values, what I'm doing wrong? How can I pass two values from the mapper to the reducer? (Eventually, I need to pass more variables to the reducer but this makes the problem a bit simpler.)

This is the error:

```
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at TotalTime$TimeReducer.reduce(TotalTime.java:57)
    at TotalTime$TimeReducer.reduce(TotalTime.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
```

and this is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class TotalTime {
    
    public static class TimeMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
        
        Text textKey = new Text();
        Text textValue = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String data = value.toString();
            String[] field = data.split(",");
            
            if (null != field && field.length == 4) {
                
                String strTimeIn[] = field[1].split(":"); 
                String strTimeOout[] = field[2].split(":");
                
                int timeOn = Integer.parseInt(strTimeIn[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(strTimeIn[1]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(strTimeIn[2]);
                int timeOff = Integer.parseInt(strTimeOout[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(strTimeOout[1]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(strTimeOout[2]);
                
                String v = String.valueOf(timeOn) + "," + String.valueOf(timeOff);
                
                textKey.set(field[0]); 
                textValue.set(v);
                
                context.write(textKey, textValue);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static class TimeReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            
            Text textValue = new Text();
            int sumTime = 0;
            
            for (Text val : values) {

                String line = val.toString();
                // Split the string by commas
                String[] field = line.split(",");
                
                int timeOn = Integer.parseInt(field[0]);
                int timeOff = Integer.parseInt(field[1]);
                
                int time = timeOff - timeOn;
                    
                sumTime += time;

            }
            String v = String.valueOf(sumTime);
            
            textValue.set(v);
            context.write(key, textValue);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "User Score");
        job.setJarByClass(TotalTime.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TimeMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(TimeReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TimeReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```

The input file looks like this:

```
ID2347,15:40:51,16:21:44,20
ID4568,14:27:57,14:58:04,72
ID8755,13:40:49,13:42:31,99
ID3258,13:12:48,13:37:11,73
ID9666,13:44:34,15:53:36,114
ID8755,09:43:59,10:47:52,123
ID3258,10:25:22,10:41:12,14
ID9666,09:40:10,11:44:01,15
```

Comment: can you include some portion of your input file in question?

Comment: I added the input file to the original post because I don't know how to properly edit it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is combiner which causes your code fails. remember combiner is a piece of code that is ran before reducer. now imagine this scenario:

your mapper process this line:

```
ID2347,15:40:51,16:21:44,20
```

and write following output to context

```
[ID2347, (56451,58904)]
```

now combiner come into play and process the output of your mapper before reducer and produce this:

```
[ID2347, 2453]
```

now above line go to reducer and it fails because in your code your assumption is the value is something like this `val1,val2`
if you want to your code work just remove combiner [or change your logic]